# How to use startup scripts in Google AI Hub Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ipython, jupyter-lab

I am hoping to use the normal Jupyter Lab (IPython) startup scripts on Google Hub AI but they don't ever seem to load. The steps I have taken are:

- Created a VM and have the lab running
- Added an `init.py` file to `/home/jupyter/.ipython/default_profile/startup/init.py`
- Restarted kernel
- Restarted jupyter service per the Hub AI docs

For starters the script just imports some stuff like numpy and pandas and prints a line. I want to use this to automatically append to the path a sibling directory along side my notebooks dir. Nothing seems to load though, no print statement and none of my imports ever load.

I have restarted the kernel many times as well as the service with no luck. Really seems like this should be doable but am stuck.